# How to format long Objective-C methods?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a short way in Xcode to format the following:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:<#(NSString *)#> message:<#(NSString *)#> delegate:<#(id)#> cancelButtonTitle:<#(NSString *)#> otherButtonTitles:<#(NSString *), ...#>, nil];
```

to

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:<#(NSString *)#>
                                                    message:<#(NSString *)#>
                                                   delegate:<#(id)#>
                                          cancelButtonTitle:<#(NSString *)#>
                                          otherButtonTitles:<#(NSString *), ...#>, nil];
```

Comment: currently, I'm manually pressing enter after every parameter...

Comment: Press enter after each parm.  Hard to believe you're defining so many messages that it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: there are many initiation methods that have expanded parameters, so why the hang up on messages? it's an inconvenience and there should be a better way to do it if there isn't

Comment: (I meant to say "methods".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excellent XCode Plugin [ClangFormat](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) by @travisjeffery. it will save you some time to press enter.

Comment: ClangFormat should be part of a default Clang installation by version 3.4 according to these release notes: http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: it is installed but not used by Xcode by default. BOTH these plugins do

Answer (score 1):

Use uncrustify code formatter: http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net
(It is VERY flexible. Virtually anything can be configured)

xcode plugin: https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode